Pushing Changes Between Environments in AWS Amplify
I’m currently working on an Amplify app on AWS and encountering issues when trying to push changes from one environment to another. I use Git to track my changes, but whenever I attempt to push all changes at once into a specific environment using amplify push, I receive an error stating 'waiting for deployment: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete.' This error has been slowing down my workflow.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues? If so, how did you resolve them? I’m looking for an easier or more reliable method to push changes without running into these problems. Any tips, tools, or best practices would be greatly appreciated

how do you push and what do you push when you use amplify push do you see he changes that is going to happen and check the status using amplify status before using push command??

Yes, I can see multiple changes using amplify status before pushing, but I've encountered issues when trying to push all changes at once. I typically have to push each change individually to avoid errors
